# HTTP protocol in Azure app (AADSTS500117)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]

When I use this URL I get this error "AADSTS500117: The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a secure scheme." I am guessing this is beacuse I am not using HTTPS, is there any way I get this app working with HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Azure does not redirect from authorization requests to non-HTTPS URLs. Localhost is the only exception. You need to use HTTPS to protect your website and make sure that the redirect you provide is HTTPS.
So you can use `http://localhost/` .